# VHDL conditional type generation (flavor of FW)

Tags: if-statement, package, vhdl, generate

I'm doing a DIY project with robots with different sensors.
So I'm trying to have the maximum common code for all of them and here I get to the question:

it's possible to do something like if..generate in the packages?
the next code is wrong but it's for illustrate what would be the best way to do it:

```
constant robo_type : integer := 1;

-- 6 legs, motors with encoders
6_legs_2_parts : if robo_type = 0 generate
    type leg_sens is record
        angle1 is array (5 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
        angle2 is array (5 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
    end record;
end generate;

-- 6 legs, motors with encoders
6_legs_3_parts : if robo_type = 1 generate
    type leg_sens is record
        angle1 is array (5 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
        angle2 is array (5 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
        angle3 is array (5 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
    end record;
end generate;

-- 4 legs motors, encoders & current
4_legs_2_parts : if robo_type = 2 generate
    type leg_sens is record
        angle1 is array (3 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
        angle2 is array (3 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
        amp1 is array (3 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 100;
        amp2 is array (3 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
    end record;
end generate;
```

Now I use something like this, and relay in that the compiler will optimize what I'm not using

```
-- generic leg_sens for all robots
constant numAngles : integer := 4;

type leg_sens is record
    angle1 is array (numAngles -1 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
    angle2 is array (numAngles -1 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
    angle3 is array (numAngles -1 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1000;
    amp1 is array (numAngles -1 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 100;
    amp2 is array (numAngles -1 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 100;
    amp3 is array (numAngles -1 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 100;
end record;
```

I found this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237770/vhdl-if-generate-in-the-preamble-is-it-possible but it isn't what I'm looking for.

So, I'm looking if it's possible to do conditionals inside the packages, 
I didn't found anything on the IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual (IEEE Std 1076™-2008)

Thanks

Comment: Generate cannot be used in a package. The final way you have dont it would be the normal way (use a constant to define the size of the fields in a record). In VHDL 2008 you can provide generics to packages, so you can have the same package with multiple instantiations with different size types.

Comment: Use an unbounded array definition in type declarations wherein array constraints are provided in object declarations. 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 General, 6.2 Type declarations, 6.3 Subtype declarations, the BNF - subtype_indication -> constraint -> array constraint. Unbounded array definitions with unconstrained elements are generally not supported for FPGA synthesis, neither are package generics (4.7 package declarations).  A value of an array composite object can provide the bounds via predefined attributes of arrays (16.2.3) easily if you use consistent direction (5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

VHDL-2008 allows composites to have unconstrained elements.   Hence, you can define the following.  No promises though if your synthesis tool will like you.  Your best bet is to use your "leg_sens" type.

```
type AngleType is array (integer range <>) of range 0 to 1000; -- regular VHDL
type AngleArrayType is array (integer range <>) of AngleType;  -- VHDL-2008

type AmplitudeType is array (integer range <>) of range 0 to 100 ;
type AmplitudeArrayType is array (integer range <>) of AmplitudeType ;

type RobotLegType is record
  Angle : AngleArrayType ;
  Amp   : AmplitudeArrayType ; 
end record RobotLegType ; 

-- 6 legs, motors with encoders
subtype Legs6Parts2Type is 
  RobotLegType( 
     Angle(1 to 2)(5 downto 0), 
     Amp(1 to 0)(5 downto 0)   -- Amp is intentionally a null array (hence empty)
  ) ; 

-- 6 legs, motors with encoders
subtype Legs6Parts3Type is 
  RobotLegType( 
     Angle(1 to 3)(5 downto 0), 
     Amp(1 to 0)(5 downto 0)   -- Amp is intentionally a null array (hence empty)
  ) ; 

-- 4 legs motors, encoders & current
subtype Legs4Parts2AmpType is 
  RobotLegType( 
     Angle(1 to 2)(3 downto 0), 
     Amp  (1 to 2)(3 downto 0)   
  ) ;
```